# Strict yaml parsing using aeson's generic parser in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, yaml

I am using the [yaml](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yaml) package for parsing .yaml files to Haskell `data` structures. Since I have quite a number of `data` objects, I am using Generics to avoid writing the "parser" each time. This looks something like

```
instance ToJSON MyData where
 toJSON = genericToJSON defaultOptions
```

However the parsing is not "strict" enough, i.e. the parser silently ignores fields that are present in the .yaml file but don't have a correspondence in the `data` structure. Is there an easy way to trigger some kind of error, if "unknown" keys are present in the .yaml file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature definitely doesn't exist in `yaml` itself, since yaml doesn't provide any code for deriving `ToJSON` and `FromJSON` instances. To my knowledge, `aeson` provides no such functionality as what you're looking for. If true, you'll have to write the instances manually.

Answer (score -1):

Below a simplified version of the code that I wrote to solve the problem. Use via `parseJSON = strictParseYaml`.

```
import Data.HashMap.Strict (member,insert,keys)

strictParseYaml xs =
 do
  parsed <- genericParseJSON defaultOptions xs
  let diff = minus (keysOfValue xs) (keysOfData parsed)
  return $
   if diff == [] then
    parsed
   else
    error $ "Found unknown keys: " ++ show diff

 where
  keysOfData u = sort $ constrFields $ toConstr u

  keysOfValue :: Value -> [String]
  keysOfValue (Object xs) = sort $ map unpack $ keys xs
```